# Java - properties as a static fields directly on class

Tags: java, properties, config

I was trying to find out any info about that on google,  but without any result.
Can someone please explain me, if there is any reason why we should load properties via config.properties,  then declaring "Properties prop",  then readinng it…  instead of directly defining static fields as properties on some class (simpler and quicker i guess).

```
Public ConfigClass{
    public static string SERVERNAME = "some hostname";
    public static string USERNAME = "some username"
}
```

And then, just calling it inside code if we need that,  e.g.

```
ConfigClass.SERVERNAME
```

I'm talking about simple scenarios,  where i want to use simple properties like,  servername,  username,  etc…

Comment: What config loader?

Comment: There is no reason why you would need to define your own extra "ConfigClass" to define static fields rather than defining them in whatever class you need them in.

Comment: @Mike e.g i want to reuse the same static field/value in few different classes (as a property) :-)

Comment: @otemek then you should define the static field in one class and create "getter" methods in that class to be able to access that static field from other classes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One advantage would be that you can change the values without having to recompile and re-deploy your code. Also, this might work for private projects but imagine you're a company with several customers where the values might be different for each customer.

Comment: Thanks for info, wasn't aware of that, that using config as a property file is a time saver 
But from the other hand, there are no any technical limitations which prevents me from using it